# How to bypass Flow's execution panel (Continue button)

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow

The execution of a Flow with a manual trigger goes like image **A**, then image **B**, so 2 clicks (and a waiting time for the Flow panel) to start a Flow.

Is there any way to **bypass the *Continue* button** of the *Execute Flow panel* (Image **B**) so that the everyday user only have to click the flow to execute (Image **A**)?

**Image A**:

[image: Image A]

**Image B**:

[image: Image B]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as it is a default behavior.

When any user wants to run the flow, he/she will be asked to authorize the connections you are using in your flow. Some connections will be authorized automatically, while other connections require users to take extra steps so that the flow works as expected.

This is like a precautionary action to make sure the user trying to run the flow should have access to all the connections used in Microsoft flow (and it is connected at time the time of running flow).

It is better to authorize the connections before flow runs than getting your flow failed after it runs.

See more at, [Authentication failures](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/fix-flow-failures#authentication-failures).

> In many cases, flows fail because of an authentication error. If you have this type of error, the error message contains **Unauthorized** or an error code of **401** or **403** appears. You can usually fix an authentication error by updating the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but like I asked Michael below, for the trigger "When a file is created / modified", there's no confirmation step for the connections as it is not possible for this kind of event, so there's no precautions to make sure the connection won't fails, so I tought there might be a way to bypass this step with the button trigger since asking the user to wait for the panel to open, than click on "Run" is just adding more steps for them. (and let's face it, the less step for the user, the better)

So the only way to avoid this button is to change the trigger... ?

Comment: As per my understanding, For manual triggers, the flow executes in the context of the current logged in user. So, he/she has to make the active connection to all the resources flow is using (Correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: That's what I want, the flow NOT to execute in the context of the current logged in user (Kind of like the Impersonation and the App Step in 2010 and 2013 workflows), so the connection should always be good since it would run with an admin account.

I was using the "On file change" event first, but I have to update the file within the same workflow, which result in a loop... but with the button (already 1 extra step), the user also have to confirm again for something which should never fail anyway. And maybe I could do it with some JS, but I feel like it wouldn't be reliable at all...

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible to bypass the step.This is by design behavior.

The Continue button of the Execute Flow panel is to make sure the connection between flow and other applications(SharePoint,Outlook...) is valid. We cannot run the flow if the connection is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this step isn't needed in other context such as "When a file is created / modified", so why is it required here?

Comment: First of all Marc, the trigger that you are using is a Manual trigger , so it will check the Validation . Now when you say that "When a file is created" , it is going to get created inside a component of O365 i.e SharePoint right ? So this means that a Valid connection with SharePoint is also necessary and hence it checks for Validation at this step as well.

Comment: @yash.kamdar, I understand that there could still be a validation step with the "When a file is created" event (SharePoint), but the user doesn't NOT have any interaction related to it. He/She just creates the document, and the flow will validate and start if the connections are OK, right?

Comment: Absolutely correct !!

Comment: I can't believe no one ever faced this issue also, (saw that kind of issue for PowerApps and connections having to be created by users, which is not user-friendly at all), so I guess (**and wish**) this is one feature that will, one day, be added to O365, after the more criticals one, since Flow is supposed to be replacing Workflows and SharePoint Designer AFAIK...